# How can I make Neovim return to the tab that was active before running `:Git diff`?

Tags: neovim, tabbed-user-interface, plugin-fugitive

How can I make Neovim automatically return to the tabpage that was active before running `:Git diff %`?

Before I commit my work in git, I often run `:Git diff` to review changes (the `:Git` command is supplied by [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)). The `:Git diff` command runs in a new instance of Neovim's terminal, which seems to open in a new tabpage of its own. I press `q` to abort the process, and the new tabpage disappears. Neovim then activates the *next available tabpage*, instead of returning to the tabpage that was active before I ran `:Git diff`.

For example, suppose that I've got Neovim running with three tabpages. If I run `1gt` to activate the first tabpage, then after running `:Git diff` I'll finish up on the second tabpage (I'll then press `gT` to go back to the tab I was working on). If I run `2gt` to activate the second tabpage, then after running `:Git diff` I'll finish up on the third tabpage (again, `gT` gets me back to where I was). If I run `3gt`, then I can run `:Git diff` and remain on the third tabpage, because it's the last one that's open.

I'd like to be able to run `1gt`, then `:Git diff`, and to be automatically returned to the first tabpage when the terminal process exits. How can I make that happen?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem here. I'm seeing that the `git diff` tab is created before the current active tab, which would make the "close-and-go-to-next" land on the good tab. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Also, from the fugitive code it would make sense for the tab to be created before the current one: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/plugin/fugitive.vim#L703

Comment: I typically use `:Gstatus`. If i am concerned with the exact nature of my commit I use the `cvc` command which does `:Gcommit --verbose` which gives the diff below the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This patch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/commit/bdd216827ae53cdf70d933bb30762da9bf42cad4) on fugitive fixes this issue (and here's [the PR](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/pull/784)). It looks like I was running an old version of fugitive. Upgrading to the latest fugitive fixed this issue for me.